# How can I download PyTorch 1.8.1 on a Raspberry Pi 3?

Tags: python

I want to download PyTorch 1.8.1 on a Raspberry Pi 3. Can this be done? If so, how?

Comment: you can download anything you want, as long as the file fits into the available storage space ... the question is unrelated to the Raspberry Pi, because the same thing would apply to a PC or a Mac

Comment: Have you read the instructions at https://pytorch.org/get-started/locally/ ... you pick your build, your OS (Linux in case you weren't aware), Package (Conda/Pip/LibTorch or Source) Language (Python or C++/Java) then the compute platform (CUDA 10, CUD 11, ROCm or CPU) ... the the command to install is shown for you .... how much easier can it be